# Help me understand a part of this code (using Clock)

Tags: plotting, dynamic, code

I'm a begginer in Mathematica and I need help understanding a part of some code that I took and adapt from another question in this forum. The code is to animate one by one a list of points (with x,y coordinates). The code is the following.

```
    Dynamic[With[{t = Clock[{1, Length[points], 1}, 50]},
    ListPlot[points[[;; t]]]]]
```

The code works just fine. I've never used clock so I don't understand this part of the code particulary

```
points[[;; t]]
```

Why are there two semicolons? What is the function of them? Why there is nothing before those semicolons?
Any light regarding this would be helpful.

Also, is there an easy way to convert this dynamic animation into a mp4 of gif file?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Look at the [documentation for `Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), that reads `expr[[m;;n]]` gives parts $m$ through $n$, and `expr[[;;n]]` from the beginning to part $n$. Notice that `expr[[i]]` is equivalent to `Part[expr,i]`.

Comment: `lis[[;;t]]` is same as `lis[[1;;t]]` which means first `t` elements of list. In Matlab this is same as `lis(1:t)`  so `;;` is similar to Matlab's `:`

Comment: The community is happy to help you, but we may not want to keep this question open for long after you solve your problem. The idea is that we want to curate only questions and answers that can help future visitors. Therefore, your question may [closed](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it is technically [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). That is because it arises from a simple mistake easily found in the documentation and it's unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning up policy. This one and all your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome.

Comment: `Clock` command can be used in many ways. In your case, it is going from the 1st to the last point in increments of one and it has to finish the simulation in 50s. I have reduced it to 5s to reduce file size. See [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbgDJ.gif).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the reply. Now I understand it. You can close the question.